# How to set Highcharts legend navigation position and layout

Tags: highcharts

Is this possible to set the legend navigation layout as vertical?
Something like this: https://d.pr/i/8wZySL
I also need to change the position (top/left) of the navigation - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility in Highcharts by default. Your suggestion has already been added on Highcharts uservoice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3356449-horizontal-legend-paging

As an alternative, you can modify default legend behavior by overwriting prototype methods:

```
H.Legend.prototype.handleOverflow = function(legendHeight) {

// Here you can overwrite method

}
```

Experimental example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2zo9hg4f/